# PHP Datepicker data doesn't go into mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am building a application for web using php and mysql database. I am using a template for the frontend, bootstrap template, however, when I choose the date and submit the form, the date doesn't go into the mysql, I have set the data type for my date as DATE in mysql. i can't seem to figure out why. Here is the code for the date.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Request Date</label>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
       <input class="input-sm input-s datepicker-input form-control" size="16" type="text" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy" name="requestDate" id="requestDate" data-required="true">
      </div>
 </div>
```

Here is the Execution code for the form:

```
<?php
include("dbconnection.php");

print_r($_POST);
$id = $_POST['id'];
$seoSro = $_POST['seoSro'];
$projectStatus = $_POST['projectStatus'];
$requestDate = $_POST['requestDate ];
------ the correct one ---------
$requestDate = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($_POST['requestDate']));
```

Please help me guys, it enters 0000-00-00 data into the database.

Comment: data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy" What is the format in your date column?

Comment: Please, post result of `var_dump($_REQUEST['requestDate']);`

Comment: there's no MySQL here, no db schema.

Comment: Where is your [tag:php] code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

mysql date format is `yyyy-mm-dd`,

so before inserting the code, use `strtotime()` and convert the date to mysql format.

```
$requestDate = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($_POST['requestDate']));
```

Comment: OP has `data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy"` so they could do `data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd"` also. While making sure their column is `date` type. Otherwise, it won't work.

Comment: @Fred-ii- usually for end users, we should show in `dd-mm-yyy` format, so keping that in mind i gave this answer

Comment: @Fred-ii- dont consider as argument, i just said what even was there in my mind for this answer.

Comment: lol I don't think you understand what I meant by that. I meant that what you said in your comment is true. I think we're having a culture clash when it comes to expressions ;-)

Comment: hi @NiranjanNRaju, I tried the solution you gave, but the data still doesn't enters my sql

Comment: @Fadil can you add the code which you have tried...??

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju i used this code inside the executer, and the form code is the same as the above.  $requestDate = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($_POST['requestDate']));